# Age restriction

Tags: rules, football

How does the age restriction rule applies in football, is there any regulation by FIFA or CAF. If a player is registered while under age, will that player still be eligible to play under that age group even if their next birth day falls within the particular football season

Comment: By "age restriction rule", are you referring to things like national under-21 squads?